# Sync issue with outlook on Windows Phone 10

Tags: sync, nokia-lumia-920, insider-preview, outlook

Outlook is having trouble syncing on my phone, sending and receiving email seems to be impossible.

I try checking the settings for the account, and it looks like the server line might be BS, but I'm not sure what to change it to.

I'm still trying things, oh... interesting... it says to try deleting the account and re-adding it, but I can't seem to figure out how to delete the account either. (error code 0x85010001)

[Edit:] Just tried to uninstall the outlook app, but it won't let me do that...

[Edit2:] Just tried setting the mail server to smtp-mail.outlook.com, which gives me error code 0x80072efd

Platform:

- Nokia Lumia Icon (929)
- Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview
- Version: 10.0.10536.1004
- Firmware: 02540.000.19.15024.38022
- Hardware: 1.0.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a post on setting up hotmail for the iphone oddly enough, that helped me.

http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/30/use-hotmail-on-the-iphone/

according to the post the proper server name is m.hotmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete primary account. If outlook account is your primary account on phone then factory reset is the only option for you.

As per the Windows service status website, outlook currently has a issues with IMAP and POP users. Web access is working fine at the moment.

Check the status here: https://portal.office.com/servicestatus